# Android : Load Image --> open failed : EACCES

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image

Android 6.0 - Marshmallow

I just want to open the gallery and pick an image but I have the error :

`E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/my_image-1.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Here is my permissions declaration in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And here is my image picker :

```
((Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_Logo)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void OnClick(View v) {
   Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GETCONTENT);
   getIntent.setType("image/*");
   Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
   pickIntent.setType("image/*");
   Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getInten, "Select Image");
   chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{pickIntent});
   startActivityForResult(chooseIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
  }
});
```

Comment: can you post some code that you use to open this file?

Comment: Please post your onActivityResult() code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For API 23+ you need to request the read/write permissions even if they are already in your manifest.

```
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
// Check if we have write permission
int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,       Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // We don't have permission so prompt the user
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            activity,
            PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
            REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    );
}
```

}

Comment: @user5658783 from marshmallow , this needed to be implemented , hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the two below permissions in manifest

> android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>   android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: which android version are you using?

Comment: android 6.0 but thanks, the problem is solved. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , please remove this line "getintent.setType(images/*)" from your intent.
And make a single intent like this...

`Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, 
                            "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);`

Comment: Ok, it changes the way to select the picture but same error.

Comment: @user5658783 make sure you have added the write and read external storage permissions outside the application tag in your manifest

Comment: @user5658783 On which android version are you getting this error ? are you using an emulator or device ?

Comment: @rd1773 On Android 6.0, a device, Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: ohhh see my other answer